# Convert string to date not same in swift 3

Tags: swift

Why? i convert string to date, input not same output?

```
Input: 
let formatter = DateFormatter() 
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
dateLahir = formatter.date(from: "2017-10-05")
print("date: \(dateLahir)")

Output: 
date: 2017-10-04
```

Comment: Show the actual complete output of `print("date: \(dateLahir)")`.

Comment: BTW - your code is fine. You just need to understand the output of printing a `Date` object.

Comment: The date formatter will convert the date string using your current timezone, whereas `print` will generally show the equivalent date/time in GMT (you'll see a `+0000` at the end, which is why rmaddy asked to to share the full string from the `print` statement). Bottom line, don't worry about what timezone `print` happens to use. Always use date formatters when converting to and from `Date` objects (e.g. if showing a date in your app, use `DateFormatter` to build the string to show the end user).

Comment: @Rob is right. just add : `let stringDate = formatter.string(from: dateLahir!)
        
        print("String date: \(stringDate)")`  and you will get the correct date.

Comment: I want to save the date in the database but the date I selected from datepicker to textfield is correct and I convert the date in textfield the result appears the previous date. Please explain if anything is missing from my coding

this example coding convert string to date

var dateLate: Date!

let formatter = DateFormatter ()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateLahir = formatter.date (from: "2017-10-05")

Comment: as mentioned by @Amit and @Bob, there is nothing wrong with your code, just `print() ` prints the time in GMT +0000. To save the date in the database, you ought to send the date in a string and work accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer @snjmhj and all...the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**
Convert Date to String

```
class func convertDateToString(_ dateStr: String?, fromDateFormat currentFormat: String, toDateFormat newFormat: String) -> String? {

    if dateStr == nil {
        return nil
    }

    let formatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = currentFormat
    let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr!)

    if date == nil {
        return ""
    }

    formatter.dateFormat = newFormat
    let newStr: String = formatter.string(from: date!)

    return newStr
}
```

**Convert string to Date**

```
class func convertStringToDate(_ strDate: String, dateFormat: String) -> Date? {
    let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent

    let date = formatter.date(from: strDate)

    return date;
}
```